# How can I generate several thumbnails for a larger image?

Tags: php, linux, image, apache, imagemagick

Given a large image (let's say at least 1200x800px), how can I generate smaller centered square and scaled thumbnails?

I need to generate several thumbnails for this image:

1. 300x300 square (centered, preferably)
2. 100x100 square (centered, preferably)
3. 600 max (width or height, scaled proportionally)
4. 100 max (width or height, scaled proportionally)

Is there a linux or php library that will help accomplish this?

Sample Image: http://placehold.it/1200x800

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [PHP Thumbnailer](http://phpthumb.gxdlabs.com/).  Simply create one thumbnail for each size you want.

Example Usage:

```
$thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create('/path/to/image.jpg');
$thumb->resize(100, 100);  // resize to 100x100
$thumb->save('/path/to/100x100.jpg');
```

Simply do that for each size you wish to save.

Check out the [docs](https://github.com/masterexploder/PHPThumb/wiki/Basic-Usage) for more examples.